# MYSQL SELECT WHERE Clause : How to include a column from another table?

Tags: mysql, select, include

In MYSQL, let's say I have following two tables.

"profile":

```
fullname | gender | country_code
-----------------------------------
Alex     | M      | us
Benny    | M      | fr
Cindy    | F      | uk
```

"country":

```
country_code | country_name
-----------------------------
jp           | Japan
us           | United States of America
fr           | France
sg           | Singapore
uk           | United Kingdom
```

While querying from `"profile"` table's perspective, like this:

```
WHERE fullname = 'Cindy'
```

Then in the result, how do i include a column from another Table (to get the results like this below):

```
fullname | gender | country_code | country_name
------------------------------------------------
Cindy    | F      | uk           | United Kingdom
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Select * from profile natural join country where fullname='Cindy'
```

Comment: I believe other answers are also nice. But this one is good enough and so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
select a.fullname, a.gender, b.country_code, b.country_name 
FROM profile a 
LEFT JOIN country b ON a.country_code = b.country_code 
WHERE a.fullname='Cindy'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to JOIN the tables. For example:

```
select a.fullname, a.gender, b.country_code, b.country_name 
  from profile a JOIN country b 
    on a.country_code = b.country_code 
 where a.fullname='Cindy'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 select fullname, gender, profile.country_code as country_code, country_name from profile join country on profile. country_code = profile.country_code where fullname = "Cindy";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use **JOIN**:

```sql
SELECT profile.*, country.country_name
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
ON profile.country_code=country.country_code
```

For more info check this : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
SELECT t1.fullname, t1.gender t1.country_code,t2.country_name
FROM profile AS t1 INNER JOIN country AS t2 ON t1.country_code = t2.country_code where t1.fullname='cindy';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select p.fullname,p.gender,p.country_code,c.country_name from profile p 
INNER JOIN country c on p.country_code=c.country_code where p.fullname='Cindy'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use join between profile and country table as below

```
SELECT
profile.fullname,
profile.gender, 
country .country_code, 
country .country_name 
FROM profile as profile JOIN country as country 
       ON (profile.country_code = country.country_code)
  WHERE profile.fullname = 'Cindy'
```